# AWS Athena Equivalent in GoogleCloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, amazon-athena

Looking for an equivalent GoogleCloud tool that can query a compressed CSV prior to decompression. Currently we use Athena for this, but are looking to transition to GoogleCloud. Is there an equivalent tool to Athena's querying of a compressed CSV, within GCP?

Comment: The closest is Google BigQuery. This article has a nice writeup comparing the two products. https://medium.com/cloudwithmore/aws-athena-vs-google-bigquery-81a5e885d5c6 The big difference is that BigQuery requires data to be imported and does not directly query data in cloud storage. Once that is done, BigQuery is much faster then Athena with possibly significant data processing cost savings.

Comment: This question is highly opinion based, and as such, violates the guidelines for asking questions. Please edit your question asking about specific attributes, not simply which is better, unless there is no other way.

Comment: AWS Athena is hosted [Presto](https://prestosql.io/). You can run Presto in any cloud and we, Starburst, make it easier: https://www.starburstdata.com/presto-on-gcp/. You can also use [Presto on Dataproc](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/initialization-actions/tree/master/starburst-presto) (there is also a Dataproc "component", but this is an old Presto version). And there is also BigQuery, as mentioned above (which can be cheap or pretty expensive, depending how you end up using it).

Comment: Appreciated. My question wasn't meant to be opinionated. I simply wanted to know if the functionality of querying a csv while compressed existed within GCP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can query [compressed CSV](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#loading_csv_data_into_a_new_table) files in BigQuery. But, before executing the query, you should ingest the compressed CSV into BigQuery. You can ingest the compressed data from many sources like Google Cloud Storage, local files, Google Cloud Bigtable and Google Drive.

Please let me know if this solution meets your requirements.